# Finding the index of a char in an array with a pointer as an argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a main function which has the code:

```
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 80;
    char ca[SIZE];
    char * pc = ca;
    int fPrints = 0;
    int bPrints = 0;
    int lengthChecks = 0;

    ReadString(pc, SIZE);
    char test = 'X';
    int index = 0;
    index = FindIndexOfCharacter(pc, test);
    std::cout << test << " index " << index << std::endl;
    test = 's';
    index = 0;
    index = FindIndexOfCharacter(pc, test);
    std::cout << test << " index " << index << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press ENTER";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

A function which reads the input

```
void ReadString(char * c, int maxLength)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a string less than " << maxLength << " characters." << std::endl;

    std::cin.getline(c, maxLength);
}
```

This function is supposed to return the index of a character in the array by using the pointer to the array and a test value and return it

```
int FindIndexOfCharacter(char * c, char testVal) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(c); i++)
    {
        if (c[i] == testVal) {
            return (int)i;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

All I get is -1 for both searches, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: _"All I get is -1 for both searches."_ What searches? You didn't show what kind of input you give to get that result. [ot] Why do you cast an `int` to an `int`? And you should probably not leave open the possibility that the compiler calls `strlen()` on every iteration of the loop. More to the point, you should not use `int` for sizes; that's why `std::size_t` exists (not that it matters until you start having strings > 2.1billionish characters long, but still...)

Comment: @underscore_d Would I be better off using a variable `length` in the function which equals strlen() and then using it in the loop?

Comment: I'd say so. For example, `for (std::size_t i = 0, len = strlen(c); i < len; ++i)`. Of course, first `#include <cstddef>` to get the declaration of `std::size_t`.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning too early in `FindIndexOfCharacter()`! If the very first character you come across doesn't match `testVal`, `FindIndexOfCharacter()` will return prematurely.

Try moving `return -1;` after the for-loop; this way, you'd return -1 only after you've checked every character in `c`:

```
int FindIndexOfCharacter(char * c, char testVal) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(c); i++)
    {
        if (c[i] == testVal) {
            return (int)i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That did it! Appreciate it!